# Including zero counts for unobserved categoricals in Pandas DataFrame value_counts

Tags: python, pandas

In Pandas, calling [value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) on a [Categorical](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html) series will make sure that each possible value gets a count even when that count is zero, all of which is subtle, [lightly documented](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html#operations), and maybe seldom cared-about, but hold on tight. We're going down a rabbit hole.

Let's say I define a [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/frame.html) with two Categorical columns like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
abc_categorical = pd.CategoricalDtype(['a', 'b', 'c'], ordered=True)
size_categorical = pd.CategoricalDtype(['s', 'm', 'l'], ordered=True)

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'a':     pd.Categorical(list('aaabababababa'), dtype=abc_categorical),
        'tsize': pd.Categorical(list('smmssmlmlslsl'), dtype=size_categorical),
    }
)
```

```
    a   tsize
0   a   s
1   a   m
2   a   m
3   b   s
4   a   s
5   b   m
6   a   l
7   b   m
8   a   l
9   b   s
10  a   l
11  b   s
12  a   l
```

### Series.value_counts

I have no rows where the 'a' column has the value 'c', so [Series.value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) gives us a zero count for it.

```py
df.a.value_counts(sort=False)
```

```
a    8
b    5
c    0
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Because we bothered to define a Categorical, Pandas knows that the column 'a' could take on the value 'c', but that never occurs in the data, so we get a 0. So far, so good.

### DataFrame.value_counts

However, if I call [DataFrame.value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html) to count values of both columns in combination, I don't get a zero either for the 'b' & 'l' combination, of which there are zero, and nothing for 'c'.

```py
df.value_counts(sort=False)
```

```
a  tsize
a  s        2
   m        2
   l        4
b  s        3
   m        2
dtype: int64
```

Bummer!

### Crosstab?

The [pandas.crosstab](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) function does a little better, giving a zero count for 'b' & 'l', but still leaves out the 'c' values.

```py
pd.crosstab(df.a, df.tsize)
```

```
tsize   s   m   l
a
    a   2   2   4
    b   3   2   0
```

### Expected results

I think, DataFrame.value_counts should return something like this:

```
            count
a   tsize
a   s       2
    m       2
    l       4
b   s       3
    m       2
    l       0
c   s       0
    m       0
    l       0
```

DataFrame.value_counts should do the same as Series.value_counts, or at least provide an option to do so, maybe "value_counts(include_zeros=True)". For that matter, crosstab should do likewise.

### My actual question

My question: Is there a concise idiomatic way to get Pandas to do the count values of categoricals *including those with zero counts*?

Note: asked in context of Pandas 2.0.1

Comment: Somewhat notably, the reason the zeroes get dropped (or rather are not added back) is because `value_counts` uses BaseGrouper.size (via GroupBy.grouper.size) instead of GroupBy.size (that happens [here in the source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/3827cafb2390824a05bc81d1bcc045c67e27606d/pandas/core/frame.py#L7073#L7073)). The primary difference being that GroupBy.size has a [`_reindex_output` phase](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/3827cafb2390824a05bc81d1bcc045c67e27606d/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py#L2316) prior to returning.

Comment: @HenryEcker. And because `observed=False` by default else `df.groupby(['a', 'tsize'], observed=True).size()` has the same behavior as `value_counts`.

Comment: That's true too and definitely a way to get the same results as `value_counts`. However, the usage of `observed` is during the [reindex function though](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/3827cafb2390824a05bc81d1bcc045c67e27606d/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py#L4077-L4078). For this reason, `df.groupby(['a', 'tsize'], observed=False).grouper.size()` and `df.groupby(['a', 'tsize'], observed=True).grouper.size()` will both produce *only* the `observed=True` results since there is no reindex and so the `observed` kwarg is effectively ignored when using BaseGrouper.

Comment: Looks like this issue is getting some love. [BUG: Inconsistent behaviour for DataFrame.value_counts and Series.value_counts on categoricals #44001](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/44001)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, [DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html#operations) respects [Categorical](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html)!

### Groupby

```py
counts = df.groupby(["a", "tsize"]).size()
counts
```

[DataFrameGroupBy.size](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.size.html) returns the number of rows in each group as a Series whose index is the cartesian product of the two categorical types.

```
a  tsize
a  s        2
   m        2
   l        4
b  s        3
   m        2
   l        0
c  s        0
   m        0
   l        0
dtype: int64
```

Awesome! All the counts and the zeros. Also, note that the tshirt sizes are in proper small, medium, large order rather than alphabetical. This is thanks to another smart bit of Pandas kit.

### CategoricalIndex

The way the index prints itself makes it look like an array of tuples of strings, but that's not what's under the hood.

```py
counts.index
```

```
MultiIndex([('a', 'l'),
            ('a', 'm'),
            ('a', 's'),
            ('b', 'l'),
            ('b', 'm'),
            ('b', 's'),
            ('c', 'l'),
            ('c', 'm'),
            ('c', 's')],
           names=['a', 'tsize'])
```

Pandas provides a [CategoricalIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.CategoricalIndex.html) and we can see them at work if we drill into the levels of the MultiIndex.

```py
counts.index.get_level_values('a')
```

```
CategoricalIndex(['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'], categories=['a', 'b', 'c'], ordered=True, dtype='category', name='a')
```

```py
counts.index.get_level_values('tsize')
```

```
CategoricalIndex(['s', 'm', 'l', 's', 'm', 'l', 's', 'm', 'l'], categories=['s', 'm', 'l'], ordered=True, dtype='category', name='tsize')
```

### Pivot table

For completeness, [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) also respects [Categoricals](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html) and gives the same results as [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

```py
pd.pivot_table(df, index=["a", "tsize"], aggfunc='size')
```

### Observed option

What if you *don't want* the zeros? Both [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) accept an 'observed' parameter that defaults to False. If observed is set to True, we only get observed values for categorical groupers, replicating the behavior of [value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html).

Nice!

Comment: Another `pivot_table` implementation: `df.pivot_table(index=['a', 'tsize'], aggfunc='size').to_frame(name='count')`